# Behavior of Swift Process.launchedProcess() vs Ruby system()

Tags: swift, shell, scripting

I'm trying to convert some Ruby code to Swift. The Ruby code launches external programs with

```
system ...
```

I've managed to get almost the same behavior with the Process API in Swift:

```
Process
  .launchedProcess(launchPath: ..., arguments: ...)
  .waitUntilExit()
```

However, there are two differences:

1. The Swift version hangs when the launched program tries to do paging (so launching "git --no-pager diff ..." works, "git diff ..." hangs if the diff is long enough).
2. If I cmd+c to interrupt while the launched program is running, my Swift script exits but the launched program keeps running. In the Ruby version, both are interrupted.

How would I avoid these issues?

**Update**: worked around issue #2 by manually terminating any launched processes when my script receives an interruption signal:

```
var globalCommand: Process? = nil // May be set later

signal(SIGINT) { _ in
  globalCommand?.interrupt()
  exit(0)
}
```